# upload or copying files / deleting

Tags: php

I am using a file in my main folder, httpdocs to execute this operations ( php ) on a "subdomain" folder that is outside the main folder.

The problem is I can't copy files, delete into that folder... the following error appears:

> Warning: opendir() [function.opendir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../ppp) is not within the allowed path(s):  in / on line 25
>
> Warning: opendir(../ppp) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Operation not permitted in  on line 25

Comment: you should show the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As PHP warning clearly states, you have a PHP instance configured to restrict your file manipulation functions to the only allowed directories. It's configured in `open_basedir` directive in your `php.ini` file.

As PHP documentation states (about `open_basedir`):

> Limit the files that can be opened by PHP to the specified
>   directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive is NOT
>   affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.

The solution is rather simple. Open your PHP configuration file (in the most of Linux environments it's stored in a `/etc/php(5?)` directory and called something like `php.ini`) and search for `open_basedir` directive. Its format is similar to format of `PATH` environment variable on variety of OS'es.

Hope it helps and I'd like to greet the SO community. It's my first post, so I'll be glad if someone points me my mistakes during answering this question. Cheers!